# How to set multiple-author metadata for an item in iBooks?

Tags: macos, icloud, books, metadata

While I can edit books' author metadata in the list view, I can’t seem to be finding a way to set multiple authors for a single title. Is there any way to do this, so that I can have, let's say, two separate author entities for a book?

```
defaults read ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/Data/Documents/iBooks/Books/Books.plist
```

---

```
...,
{
      BKAllocatedSize = 131072;
      BKDisplayName = "An Introduction To Software Architecture";
      BKGeneratedItemId = 409BAEEB1FD9D2272D63E97BFB7CDEBD;
      BKGenerationCount = 3;
      BKInsertionDate = 558100869;
      BKIsLocked = 0;
      artistName = "David Garlan, Mary Shaw";
      explicit = 0;
      isPreview = 0;
      itemName = "An Introduction To Software Architecture";
      metadataMigrationVersion = 20140106;
      modificationDate = "2000-11-13 17:55:48 +0000";
      pageCount = 42;
      path = "/Users/Sepehr/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~apple~iBooks/Documents/An Introduction To Software Architecture.pdf";
      releaseDate = "2000-11-13 12:55:48 +0000";
      sourcePath = "/Users/Sepehr/Books/An Introduction To Software Architecture.pdf";
      updateDate = "2000-11-13 17:55:48 +0000";
      versionNumber = 0;
},
...
```

How can I get more than one author added in the metadata for an iBooks document?

Comment: Kindly [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/337227/edit) the question to clearly specify your query.

Comment: I don’t get the close votes. This is pretty clearly asking about how to edit the filesystem metadata for files that the books reader will use. Please flag this for reopening if it somehow gets closed and an edit to explain your OS requirements doesn’t get it reopened.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you are struggling with defining several authors for an iBook. Yet your code example shows only a read command and properties with several authors included. What have you tried to define several authors?

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear enough. That's exactly what I want to do; multiple authors for a book. So that I can have those authors as separate authors in the Authors tab. I tried different formattings, using semicolons, commas, etc. But it seems to be updating that `artistName` key as just a string. Also tried updating ePub files using Calibre to no avail.

Comment: So you basically want several `artistName` entries in the metadata structure? Not sure this is even possible (keys must be unique), do you have an example of an iBook where it is defined as such?

Comment: And: in the example given there are multiple authors. Is this not what you want? The question would benefit a lot if you could include (in the question, not in a comment) an example of what you want to see at the end.

Answer (score 0):

All this metadata exists on the filesystem, so you could use the `xattr` command line to change pretty much anything, but I find the documentation and syntax to be very challenging to get and use.

I would start by trying xattred editor and perhaps the easier tools SearchKey / SearchKeyLight

- https://eclecticlight.co/downloads/

The author has a very superb blog explaining why the app was made in the first time and how to use it as well if you don’t get the buttons or features. Think of all these metadata as a key value store. You just name the attribute (like modification date) and then set a value (today’s date or whatever). Same for page count and in your case, the author metadata string type.

Since you are reading the overall catalog, I would focus on changing the metadata in each book one by one (perhaps working on a throwaway ebook or duplicate copy of a book if you don’t have a good backup and restore procedure for the books you store in iCloud).

Comment: To give you an update, there's this [`com.apple.iBooks.author#S` xattr attribute](https://i.imgur.com/W9P96UD.png) on iBooks epub/pdf files which is of type String. I don't think I can change to something like a multivalue key, or to create a duplicate key. I also tried the app you suggested, no way there as well. It only allows you to edit the string content of the key as string.

Comment: And trying to set a duplicate attr, obviously overwrites the previous value. `xattr -w "com.apple.iBooks.author#S" "Another author here" "Design Patterns Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software.epub"`.